# SQL query problem in table with self-referencing parent ID

Tags: sql-server-2008, parent-child, self-join

First the relevent schema:

A is a table of list entries with ListID, Date, and ItemID

B is a table of the underlying items with ID and owner (which is currently text).

C is a table of the owners with ID (int), Name (varchar) and Parent (int).
Parent is either the ID of another member or null if it is a top-level node.  This table is only 2 levels deep so every member is either a child or parent.

A.ItemID points to B.ID
B.Owner points to C.Name
C.Parent is either null or points to another C.ID

Now the problem...

I need to count the number of entries on a given list (ListID and Date) for each parent in C.  I almost have it with one problem.  Query is:

```
select C.owner, COUNT(B.ID) as Count from A  
join B on A.ItemID = B.ID  
join C on B.Owner= C.Owner  
join C2 on C.Parent = C2.ID   
Where date = '2011-01-10' and ListID = 1  
Group by C2.Owner  
order by C2.Owner
```

But it is only counting entries that match up with child rows in C.  Because the parent rows don't have their own ID in the parent field, they aren't being included in the aggregate counts even though there are items that are directly owned by parents in table C.  I am fairly sure that I could solve the problem by putting those values in, but that seems like bad design as those rows would effectively be their own parents.

Is there a way to manage this query to account for this?  I'm stumped.

Alternatively, is it 'okay' to have rows reference themselves as a parent for purposes of aggregating their own data with those of their children?

Thanks for any and all advice here.  If this isn't clear, I can be more specific but I'm trying to keep unrelated information out of it.

-Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a left-join on C and C2.

```
C LEFT JOIN C2 ON C.Parent = C2.ID
```

This will cause all rows to be included from C, and, if there is a corresponding child in C2, that will be included as well.

Comment: First, sorry about the bad formatting. Fixed. I tried the Left join and saw no change, but in thinking on it futher, I then tried the Left join above it (Left Join C on B.Owner = C.Owner) and I got what seems to be the correct number in my counts now but they show up as Null owners, which may be right. I may have some null owners in B.  I need to look at the data more to confirm, but this is either the answer, or a step closer. I'll circle back with a check once I can confirm tonight. Thanks!

Comment: doing some end-of-year housekeeping, I found I eventually did put the ParentIDs into the records that were parents.  No downside to this.